# Windows FOR loop compared to DIR command

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cmd.exe

Can someone explain this difference.

Given a directory which contains the following files/dirs:

```
09-Sep-16  14:14    <DIR>          ignoreMe
09-Sep-16  14:13    <DIR>          ignore.me
09-Sep-16  14:13                 0 myfile1.txt
09-Sep-16  14:13                 0 myfile2.txt
```

The command:  `for %i in (*) do echo %i` will ouput:

```
myfile1.txt
myfile2.txt
```

(meaning it only outputs files, not dirs)

However this command: `dir *` will output:

```
ignoreMe
ignore.me
myfile1.txt
myfile2.txt
```

(meaning it outputs files *and* dirs)

Notice that **the same GLOB is used in both cases, yet they produce different results**. Shouldn't it be consistent ?

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the options you have:

- files : `for %i in (*) do @echo %i`
- subdirs: `for /D %i in (*) do @echo %i`

You can't have both results in a single `for` statement, because *subdirs* is a switch (**/D**) inside the command that modifies the output of it.

For further explanations type `for /?` in *cmd*.

Comment: Hmm. If the [GLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) pattern `*` by definition returns those four elements (in *any* context) then you are saying that `FOR` (no modifiers) command will implicitly remove all dirs from the glob result while `FOR /D` will remove all files from the glob result ?. What if I wanted nothing removed from the glob result in a FOR-loop? I just don't get it coming from another OS, that's all.

Comment: @PeterHansson You can blame MS for that. I think that `PowerShell`has solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, coming from another OS then `CMD` seems to be a shell which contradicts itself constantly. Probably everything should be done in PowerShell these days. :-)